# How to validation depend on different submit buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activestorage

My application has "save_button", "check_button" and "submit_button" and I want to have validation only, if I click "submit_button" to avoid if someone does not attach any files(tape_files) and submit.

```
Model:
validates :tape_files, attached: true, on: :update
```

```
View:
<%= f.submit "Save", name: "save_button" %>
<%= f.submit "Check", name: "check_button" %>
<%= f.submit "Submit", name: "submit_button" %>
```

```
def update
    @tape.update(tapes_params)
    if params[:save_button]
      redirect_to tapes_path, notice: "Saved!"
    elsif params[:check_button]
      redirect_to tapes_path, notice: "Checked!"
    elsif params[:submit_button]
        redirect_to tape_file_tape_path(@tape.id), notice: "Attachment Saved!"   
    end
```

I found that "save(false)" has an ability to skip the validation but I have really no idea how can I integrate it into the validation.
Does someone know how the validation should be modified only for "submit_button" validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard for me to offer more than a code fix here as I don't understand the entire use case of your code and domain but have you explored the use of a [custom context with `on`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on)?

Changes you could explore with your code, if I understand you want the validation to run only when the `submit_button` is clicked. Otherwise I hope you get the idea of how to customize it for your exact needs.

```
Model:
# You can change the context to be a custom one, 
# or use multiple e.g. on: [:update, :submitted]
validates :tape_files, attached: true, on: :submitted
```

```
def update
  # [1] Change to assign_attributes
  @tape.assign_attributes(tapes_params)

  if params[:submit_button] 
    # [2] This will run all validations without an explicit
    # context PLUS the `:submitted` ones.
    if @tape.save(context: :submitted)
      redirect_to tape_file_tape_path(@tape.id), notice: "Attachment Saved!"
    else
      render 'edit', notice: "Update failed"
    end
  else
    # [3] This will run all validations without an explicit context.
    if @tape.save
      if params[:save_button]
        redirect_to tapes_path, notice: "Saved!"
      elsif params[:check_button]
        redirect_to tapes_path, notice: "Checked!"
      else
        # [Optional] You may want to consider handling a default redirect here
      end
    else
      render 'edit', notice: "Update failed"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `save!` will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` if it fails, meaning you should likely have a handler for this to avoid the "We're Sorry something went wrong" page

Comment: Yes @engineersmnky that is intentional because without other code changes his code is presently silently failing and giving a false positive.

Comment: I wasn't saying your code was a bad idea it was simply a comment as to what is going to happen when it fails and to provide a course of action for resolution of that concern. The comment was more for the OP than yourself as it is likely to be the next question after implementing your proposal.

Comment: The "tape_files" was validated, if I clicked "submit_button" but not other buttons. Wonderful! Thanks a lot, Matthew!  But I could not show the error messages as @engineersmnky wrote. So, I modified the controller a little bit. I add it as an answer.

Comment: @frankyorg I updated my answer so you can see how to display the errors. in your answer you're not actually saving the record.

Comment: @Matthew, you are right. I forgot to write "save" in my answer... I corrected it now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem as below:

```
Model:
validates :tape_files, attached: true, on: :submit_button
```

```
Controller:
def update
 @tape.assign_attributes(tapes_params)   
  if params[:submit_button]     
     @tape.valid?(:submit_button)
     if !@tape.errors.any?
        redirect_to tape_file_tape_path(@tape.id), notice: "Attachment Saved!"
     else
        render 'edit', notice: "Update failed"
     end
    
  elsif params[:save_button]
      redirect_to tapes_path, notice: "Saved!"
  elsif params[:check_button]
      redirect_to tapes_path, notice: "Checked!"
  end
  @tape.save
end
```